# Domain of functions that involve composition

Tags: functions

Suppose the domain of $f$ is $(-1,1)$. Define the function $\ell$ by
$$\ell(x)=f\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right).$$ What is the domain of '$ \ell $'

Comment: Well, which $x$ satisfy $-1<\frac{x+1}{x-1}<1$?

Comment: -x and x-2? I believe

Comment: I'm not sure because x-1 could be negative

Comment: can someone at least get me started

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, you want to solve: $$-1< \frac{x+1}{x-1} < 1$$for $x$. Rewrite $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{x-1}$, so that: $$-1< \frac{x+1}{x-1} < 1 \implies -1 < 1 + \frac{2}{x-1} < 1 \implies -1 < \frac{1}{x-1} < 0.$$Can you solve that last one now?

Comment: is it (-1,0)???

Comment: I don't know, I haven't finished the calculation. That's your task, right? Why don't you write your steps, so I can check them? :)

Comment: times x-1 on both sides then we get -x+1<1<0. Then we have 0<x<-1

Comment: Not sure if that's right because x-1 could be negative as well

Comment: Hm, not quite. Since $1/(x-1) < 0$ and $1 > 0$, we must have $x-1 < 0$. So when you multiply both sides of $-1 < 1/(x-1)$ by $x-1$, the inquality swaps and you get $(-1)(x-1) > 1$. Ok?

Comment: wait what I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: what is the full inequality that I need to solve then if x-1<0

Comment: If $b<c$ and $a < 0$, then $ab > ac$. I just used this basic property there. I used $1/(x-1) < 0$ to conclude that $x-1 < 0$. With this, we proceed to solve $-1 < 1/(x-1)$.

Comment: that's simply $x>1$

Comment: is that right??

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = -1$ when $x = 0$, and $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \to 1$ when $x \to -\infty$. And $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ is a decreasing function there.

Therefore, if $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \in (-1,1)$, the domain of $f$. Then $x \in (-\infty,0]$, the domain of $l$.